# A detail about the Fork-Join Framework

Tags: java, fork-join

In Doug Lea's paper "A Java Fork/Join Framework":

http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf

In 2.1 Work-Stealing he says:

> When a worker thread encounters a join operation, **it processes other
>   tasks**, if available, until the target task is noticed to have
>   completed (via isDone). All tasks otherwise run to completion without
>   blocking.

so can anyone tell me specifically where these **"other tasks"** come from? are they from other workerthreads' task queues? does that mean whenever a workerthread encounters a join call, it proceeds with "stealing tasks from other threads" instead of "skipping to other tasks in its own queue"?

Comment: You may want to read the cilk papers about work stealing if you want more details about that. The java version is not identical to leisersons work, but quite similar and leiserson describes it in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "other tasks" may come from within its own deque when there are pending tasks, other thread's deques, or from the submission queue of new requests.

The join() is a rather difficult procedure. It involves task control, that is, the ability to control tasks when they are active processing and suspended waiting for something. Doing this in an application usually doesn't work. (The operating systems does this well and Cilk, JCilk do it by using a compiler/runtime.) Doug Lea uses "continuation threads" when joins bog down the worker threads.

Comment: As far as I can understand the way deques(double-ended queues) work, only three operations are supported by a deque: "pop","push" and "steal"(or stolen from), and all of them work only either the head task or the tail task of the queue. In this case, how does a worker thread skip the head task (given the head task encounters a "join" operation) and proceed with "other pending tasks in the same queue" and later on come back to the skipped task?

Comment: The top of the deque is only used by other threads to steal work. The bottom of the deque is only used by the current thread to add/poll tasks. When the current thread polls it removes a task. If that task issues a join() the current thread or a "continuation thread" looks for tasks at the bottom of the deque. Look at the code. It is unbelievably complex. Especially the proposed Java8 version.